# How to declare the type for 'instanceof'

Tags: typescript

I want to get derived class objects from the base class array with `instanceof`.It's easy to do so, but I don't know how to decare the appropriate type for `ctor` to limit and prompt type of it.`ctor` should be `Base` or  derived class of it

```js
abstract class Base {

}

abstract class A extends Base {

}

class B extends A {

}

function Get<T extends Base>(base: Base[], ctor: any): T | null {
    for (let i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
        if (base[i] instanceof ctor) {
            return base[i] as T
        }
    }
    return null
}

const a = Get([], A)
const b = Get([], B)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=21#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gLABQJAviSaJDPEquggIII4AeEOAdgCYbZg8RUsQoiUafqw7c+zApVGKAZgFcu8AJYB7LggDiOCAB4AKtM69+uAHwAKELgBcWXAG0AugBokEbVBdgLgBPAEoXcwAfBC5VZGQFYgRkhGV-BDtkIwRNBABeBAAGAG4chGMER0EAOiyuAHMIAAtSzQBqNtDElJ6c5QyqnDdNDxyuSCDYHG1++H8u4V6lhCgjVSg9QeHRtARTEmWEMR7jlNWIdb1Y+PJFWF1IBGB8gyM7Tx8mUJJ78cQQF6GCDvbxYUJAA)

Comment: just curious what your end goal is?

Comment: I want to limit and prompt type of `ctor`.`ctor` should be `Base` or  derived class of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Constructor<T> = Function & { prototype: T };

abstract class Base {

}

abstract class A extends Base {

}

class B extends A {

}

function Get<T extends Base>(base: Base[], ctor: Constructor<T>): T | null {
    for (let i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
        if (base[i] instanceof ctor) {
            return base[i] as T;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

const a = Get([], A);
const b = Get([], B);
```